# Override an open source Rails APP views, without editing the original views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I am currently working with a ROR App. The problem is the app was not created with much customization in mind.

Note: This is a ROR **APP**, and **not an engine**

I would like to:

- over-ride the current views
- Avoid editing the views in the app source code
- Change the template language from .slim (which it is currently) to .erb

I tried converting the app to an engine, mounting it and then creating the views. Which will over-ride the ones in the app.

Though this does not work, and would take a significant amount of time to make it 'engine' ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way, in fact, is to use app as an engine. How difficult it is, depends on current app. But I, personally, can`t see much differences between modify view source code directly, or copy entire view code and modify it in another place. Views, in general, are not "inherit" each other, so you will have to copy-paste and edit the same code as in app source code.

By the way, if you want to easily make it engine-ready, you could try just extract views folder (and, if needed, helpers, assets) and put it in an engine and leave all the stuff (controllers, modules, routes etc) in you main app. Then, in main app you could create views with respective path, copy its content from engine and modify only them.

But for such or similar purpose there is a gem [Deface](https://github.com/spree/deface) which is used in [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) to make it easy for extensions to interact together. The point this gem, that original views are not modified and you create `deface` overrides files, that, using Nokogiri (css,xpath) syntax, change real views content in runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. While this is not ideal, it took me about a very short while just to extract the views into an engine, then override it in the app. I am going to submit a PR to the app.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you can use the command `render "name_of_custom_view"` to override an action's default view. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

Isn't the .erb template language supported out of the box? Try naming your custom views *.html.erb instead of *.html.slim.

Comment: Yes, erb is the default.

Comment: I am going to edit this question, as disabling slim is another issue altogether.